# How to replace only integers in a string by a string

Tags: python

How to replace only integers in a string by a string

My script:

```
x="the number 1234, today the 909090 of the value of the 90.94"
# by the way the has to be proposed to get the123abd 123the" by a string "ItWasanINT""

re.sub(r'\b\d+(?!\.\d+)\b','ItWasanINT',x)
```

...Not working

Comment: You mean the `90.94` value should not be replaced?

Comment: Why don't you document the post-substitution value your code generates, and what you'd like it to generate?

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to exclude numbers that are both not preceded by a "number." combo and not followed by a ".number" combo:

```
re.sub(r'\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?!.\d)\b','ItWasanINT', x)
```

Result:

```
>>> import re
>>> x="the number 1234, today the 909090 of the value of the 90.94"
>>> re.sub(r'\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?!\.\d)\b','ItWasanINT',x)
'the number ItWasanINT, today the ItWasanINT of the value of the 90.94'
```